# website different output in windows/android and apple ecosystem

Tags: css, reactjs, web

first, i'm sorry if my english bad.
the problem is,
i don't know what's happening here, but my website site if you open it in safari or chrome on IOS or MacOs is not the same like in the windows10 or android

look at the List of receiving countries on picture,
in windows and android its what i expected

[ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp57W.jpg)

[android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w240e.jpg)

here's the css properties for LIST OF RECEIVING COUNTRIES

```
  width: 336px;
  color: #48a9b5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "GothamLight";
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: calc(50% - (336px / 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm wrong but I think your problem is caused by different dimensions of the displayed area. The phone is longer. Maybe i try more media queries and add something like webkit and other.